# Kotlin Enums: function that refers to whatever Enum Object it's called from

Tags: enums, kotlin

I am trying to write an enum function `print()` that can be called as follows, from an object in the enum `Molecule`:

```
Molecule.HYDROGEN_MOLECULE.print()
myMolecule.print()
```

I don't want to have to feed the function a specific Enum Object:

```
Molecule.print(Molecule.HYDROGEN)
```

However, when I create the function in `Molecule`, I get an error when I try to reference the List of `MolecularFragment`.

What syntax I need to use in  print() to make something like `myMolecule.print()` reference the list of `MolecularFragment` for that particular enum object?

```
enum class Molecule (val MolecularFragments : List<MolecularFragment> = emptyList()) {

    HYDROGEN_MOLECULE(listOf(MolecularFragment.H2)),

    WATER_MOLECULE(listOf(MolecularFragment.H2O)),
    // ...
    HEXANE_MOLECULE(listOf(MolecularFragment.CH3, MolecularFragment.CH2));

    fun print() {

        **var x : List<MolecularFragment> = Molecule.MolecularFragments**
        x.forEach() {
            println("$it")
        }
        println(" --- ${Molecule.toString()}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Just write `var x: List<MolecularFragment> = MolecularFragments`. By the way, the convention in Kotlin is to name properties with the first letter in lower case. Like `molecularFragments`.

Comment: think of the enum class methods the same as you would think of normal class methods. Your object (in an enum: your enum constant) accesses every field/property with `this`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this does exactly what you want:

```
enum class MolecularFragment { H2, H2O, CH3, CH2 }

enum class Molecule (val molecularFragments : List<MolecularFragment> = emptyList()) {

    HYDROGEN_MOLECULE(listOf(MolecularFragment.H2)),

    WATER_MOLECULE(listOf(MolecularFragment.H2O)),

    HEXANE_MOLECULE(listOf(MolecularFragment.CH3, MolecularFragment.CH2));

    fun print() {
        molecularFragments.forEach(::println)
        println("${this::class.java.toString()}")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Molecule.HYDROGEN_MOLECULE.print()
}
```

A couple of notes:

- Your line highlighted in double asterisks didn't even compile.
- You can use a function reference to print the elements.
- You don't need to put the property `molecularFragments` in a variable first.
- Next time, please specifiy `MolecularFragment` so that the code can run right away.

Comment: Thanks, I had also tried a similar syntax as your solution but didn't get it to compile either. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use approach similar to this:

```
enum class MyType(val subTypes: List<String>) {

    FIRST_TYPE(listOf("one", "two")),
    SECOND_TYPE(listOf("three", "four"));
}

//Honestly his method could be moved in some util .kt file
    fun printOneType(myType: MyType) {
        myType.subTypes.forEach { print(it.toString()) }
    }
```

If you're having trouble with printing your sub-objects within inner collections of enums, then maybe their `toString()`s or other util methods are not implemented well - just an option.

**EDIT**. The solution of topic starter's issue was much simpler. Anyway, in case of inner collections of enums you could do:

```
enum class MyType(val otherTypes: List<OtherType>) {

    FIRST_TYPE(listOf(OtherType.FIRST)),
    SECOND_TYPE(listOf(OtherType.SECOND));
}

//Honestly his method could be moved in some util .kt file
fun printOneType(myType: MyType) {
        myType.otherTypes.forEach { print(it.name) }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems rather what the OP didn't want in the first place. Your first method `printAll` should rather be a static variant (companion object's method), not a member method. The later should rather look as follows: `fun print() = subTypes.forEach(::println)` which you call using `FIRST_TYPE.print()` instead of `FIRST_TYPE.printOneType(SECOND_TYPE)` which doesn't make that much sense.

Comment: Yup, just realized that and made some addition: maybe someone will need  simple syntax like this in the future.

Comment: I don't think that you got, what i mean. Your `printOneType`-method is a member function and it is possible to call `FIRST_TYPE.printOneType(SECOND_TYPE)`, which really doesn't make sense.

Comment: And that's why i commented that method like this should be moved to some util .kt file or class.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make much sense neither. If you really want such a method, you would probably put it in the enum's `companion object`. However, printing a single enum should rather be a member function on that enum itself.

Comment: Generally, agreed :) Though at first I thought that author tries to achieve smth like this.

Answer (score 0):

As @marstran already pointed out in the comments: remove the `Molecule` from the line you marked, so that it looks like:

```
var x : List<MolecularFragment> = MolecularFragments
```

or if you want:

```
var x : List<MolecularFragment> = this.MolecularFragments
```

An enum class method accesses `this` enum value's values and is not a singleton or static method.

Alternatively you may also supply a generic extension function which allows printing any enum at any time:

```
fun <T : Enum<T>> Enum<T>.printIt() = toString().also(::println)
```

This way you only need to override the `toString()`-method and can even reuse that `toString`-method for other purposes, e.g. an example override:

```
enum class Molecule ... {
  // ...
  override fun toString(): String {
      return super.toString() + ": $molecularFragments"
  }
}
```

.. and as @marstran also pointed out: The most common code convention in Kotlin is to start properties with a lower case letter.